# Python Why can't I send a Tweet?

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to send automated Tweets using python.

I have tried two different packages python-twitter and tweepy but have not been successful using either package. Those solutions are discussed here:

[Twitter API: simple status update (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473320/twitter-api-simple-status-update-python)
[How to tweet from Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289473/how-to-tweet-from-django)

Firstly, I should make clear that I have just created a Twitter account a couple of hours ago from which to send tweets. Using dev.twitter.com, I have set the access level to "Read, write, and direct messages" and I have created consumer and access token keys.

Using these keys, I connect to twitter using the python-twitter package. I know it is at least partially working because I can access The Biebs tweets:

```
>> CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXX'
>> CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXX'
>> ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY= 'XXXX'
>> ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET= 'XXXX'

>> import twitter
>> api = twitter.Api()
>> api = twitter.Api(
>>     consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY, 
>>     consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET, 
>>     access_token_key=ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, 
>>     access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
>> )

>> statuses = api.GetUserTimeline("justinbieber")
>> for s in statuses:
>>     print s.text    

http://t.co/q58qksxp its not finished but heres a little part a song I'm working on
sorry http://t.co/Vtu4Lc2Q
video is at 13 percent done uploading
<... Other Inanities from The Bieb Snipped. You get the picture...>
```

However, when I try to send a tweet, I get the error: "Could not authenticate with OAuth."

```
>> api.PostUpdate('Testing Twitter!')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_twitter-0.8.5-py2.7.egg/twitter.py", line 2838, in PostUpdate
    data = self._ParseAndCheckTwitter(json)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_twitter-0.8.5-py2.7.egg/twitter.py", line 3869, in _ParseAndCheckTwitter
    self._CheckForTwitterError(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_twitter-0.8.5-py2.7.egg/twitter.py", line 3892, in _CheckForTwitterError
    raise TwitterError(data['error'])
twitter.TwitterError: Could not authenticate with OAuth.
```

Can someone explain why?
Since that didn't work, I decided to install and try tweepy.

But when I try to use it, it gives me the error "Invalid or expired token"

```
>> import tweepy
>> def tweet(status):
>>     '''
>>     updates the status of my twitter account
>>     requires tweepy (https://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy)
>>     '''
>>     if len(status) > 140:
>>         raise Exception('status message is too long!')
>>     auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
>>     auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
>>     api = tweepy.API(auth)
>>     result = api.update_status(status)
>>     return result    
>>     
>> result = tweet('Testing Twitter!')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in tweet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.0-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 185, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.0-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 168, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Invalid or expired token', u'code': 89}]
```

What is the solution here?
Are my keys from Twitter wrong?

Comment: Almost -1 for accessing "The Biebs" tweets, couldn't you have exampled someone else? ;)

Comment: I wanna -1 for JB so bad...but won't. Anyway, you actually need to authenticate via oauth first, before posting. By authenticating I mean being redirected to twitter page where you click 'authorize app' and it gives you auth token in return (when authorized).

Comment: This place can get pretty dry, so I thought I'd give everyone a chuckle with the Bieber reference :)

Jan, I looked around and could not understand or locate what you are getting at. Could you please be more explicit or more idiot-proof?

Comment: FYI, the python-twitter approach worked now!
Same thing I tried yesterday didn't work. Does the Twitter account have to be at least a few hours old before it works?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you redacted them or just forget to put them in your code, but you need your authentication keys in order to access the twitter account.

The process is outlined here:
http://www.pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-tweepy-twitter-for-python/

Comment: Could improve this by trying to add some content to the answer and not just a link.